# How to change background color of DataGridViewComboBoxColumn items at run time?

Tags: vb.net

I need to set the "red" color of some elements (like capacity>20) in my  DataGridViewComboBoxColumn so I tried to get this result in my combo[1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/1019114)
from this site:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/eb870646-1da3-4217-9de0-5a398b967af2/how-to-change-background-color-of-combobox-items-at-run-time

I already populated it and it worked well. I tried to modify this class but it did not work

```
Class CustomComboDataGridViewColumn : Inherits DataGridViewComboBoxColumn


Protected Overrides Sub OnDrawItem(e As DrawItemEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnDrawItem(e)
    Dim item As CComboboxItem = DirectCast(Me.Items(e.Index), CComboboxItem)
    Using ForeBrush As Brush = New SolidBrush(item.Forecolor)
        Using BackBrush As Brush = New SolidBrush(item.Backcolor)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(BackBrush, e.Bounds)
            e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(0, e.Bounds.Y)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(item.ToString, Me.Font, ForeBrush, 0, 0)
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub


Class CComboboxItem

Public Sub New(Value As Object, Color As Color, BackColor As Color)
    Me.Value = Value
    Me.Forecolor = Color
    Me.Backcolor = BackColor
End Sub

Public Property Value As Object = Nothing
Public Property Forecolor As Color = Color.Black
Public Property Backcolor As Color = Color.Black
```

OnDrawItem is not included in this class DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Comment: please try to use linq to find your criteria, and then each cell you found, change the background color, yourdatagridvied.items(Your_ColumnIndex, Each_Cell_Found).Style.backcolor=your color. Or you can check from fisrt row to last row, and compare to your criteria, and change your back color's cells. And for All, before you take action, change the all cells to normal color

Comment: What error do you get? *but it did not work* is not clear enough.

Comment: Sorry. did not work OnDrawItem function is not included in this class DataGridViewComboBoxColumn